# SQLiteQueryBuilder vs Simple String

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I trying to make my app as fast and reactive as it possible. I wonder what is better, using simple String object or to use SQLiteQueryBuilder.

Comment: Is your app slow? unresponsive? search for the bottleneck. Is it actually the sql requests?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by *"simple String object"* but generally spoken, you can be quite sure that any in-memory operation with `Strings` will be much faster than database operations.

However, this is not an indicator for SQLite being a bad database (regarding performance), but rather a result of a robust system that persists its data to the file system, that offers ACID transactions and supports the SQL92 standard (just to mention some features). If you don't need these features and if you want maximum performance: store everything in *"simple String objects"*.

If you want to take advantage of some database features above, you might consider using SQLite as an in-memory database. See [`SQLiteOpenHelper()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) for more details.

Looking at SQLite you are advised to dig into prepared statements, transaction contexts and indices for best performance (see for instance articles [#1](http://www.android-app-market.com/sqlite-optimization-in-android-programming-sqlite-optimization-in-android-apps.html) and [#2](http://tech.vg.no/2011/04/04/speeding-up-sqlite-insert-operations/)).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Fast as possible SQL requires an indexed database.  The actual means of querying has little effect on the speed of execution.  IE you select order by field2 you should have an index on field2.

QueryBuilder also eliminates common coding errors.  Getting the delimiters correct is done for you when you pass in the selectionArgs.

Query Builder within a content provider for SQLite the query Builder paramaters match the content provider parameters.

//Example simple select by id with query builder from content provider Uri.

```
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(KEY_ID + "="
                + uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: This is wide open for SQL injection

Comment: Last segment of the URI should be numeric.  I suppose you should also check that it is numeric to be safe.